# Erro ao usar Refile + AWS SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
gem "mini_magick"
gem "refile", require: ["refile/rails", "refile/image_processing"]
gem "aws-sdk"
```

Meu arquivo config/initializers/refile.rb

```
require "refile/backend/s3"

aws = {
  access_key_id: ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
}
Refile.cache = Refile::Backend::S3.new(prefix: "cache", **aws)
Refile.store = Refile::Backend::S3.new(prefix: "store", **aws)
```

Quando executo rails s, mostra esse erro:

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/refile-0.4.2/lib/refile/backend/s3.rb:14:in `initialize': uninitialized constant Refile::Backend::S3::AWS (NameError)

Comment: Ruby 2.2.0, Rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava com o mesmo erro, coloquei a versão do aws-sdk no gemfile e funcionou:

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```